# online tool for generating stubs for webservices jax-rpc

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

is there any tool that generates stubs for RPC style wsdl online. I used the Netbeans plugin for RPC and tried to create one. But while executing the app I am getting errors like while calling a function.

```
java.rmi.RemoteException: Runtime exception; nested exception is:
    deserialization error: unexpected element type: expected=
{http://account.type.engine.mdsp.huawei.com}UserBalanceInfo, actual=
http://account.engine.mdsp.huawei.com}UserBalanceInfo
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you creating stubs by giving URL? Is your URL to WSDL correct? Does it end with a '?wsdl' ?

Comment: @sreehari i have wsdl file. url is correct. have generated the stubs properly. but execution time such errors occurs

Comment: @sreehari pls find the file at http://pastebin.com/18hgiwFZ

Comment: @sreehari i hav created the stubs with apache axis. but am not getting the procedure to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

I would say using a tool like SoapUI will enable you to create stubs or even script out responses for your wsdl services.

SoapUI supports many configuration options. for example, you can mimic your existing services with specific header values or other payloads by using groovy scripts.

Link1: http://www.guru99.com/webservice-testing-beginner-guide.html

Link2: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/getting-started.html